# Is any magic method called on an object in a list during join()?

Tags: python, join, magic-methods

Joining a list containing an object - is there any magic method I could set to convert the object to a string before join fails?

```
', '.join([…, Obj, …])
```

I tried `__str__` and `__repr__` but neither did work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, there's no `join` hook (although I've wanted this feature as well).  Commonly you'll see:

```
', '.join(str(x) for x in iterable)
```

or (almost) equivalently:

```
', '.join(map(str,iterable))
', '.join([str(x) for x in iterable])
```

---

(Note that all of the above are equivalent in terms of memory usage when using CPython as `str.join` implicitly takes your generator and turns it into a tuple anyway.)